# ORACLE SQL - interval is small

Tags: oracle, date-formatting

I am not the database specialist, so how can we solve the problem? I can help you that this code is running very well in 4 out of 5 columns, but the problem is with the column where values are like 2999 year. I think that this is the issue, but as I mentioned Im not db specialist :D

CODE:

```
TO_CHAR(
   CAST(
      FROM_TZ(
         CAST(TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000' + NUMTODSINTERVAL(VALUE_KEY.VALUE/1000, 'SECOND') AS TIMESTAMP),
         'GMT'
          )
          AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Warsaw' AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
      ),
      'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS:FF3TZHTZM'
) AS "New Date Format",
```

And I have issue like this while running query:

ORA-01873: the leading precision of the interval is too small
01873. 00000 -  "the leading precision of the interval is too small"
*Cause:    The leading precision of the interval is too small to store the
specified interval.
*Action:   Increase the leading precision of the interval or specify an
interval with a smaller leading precision.

What is more interesting when I change the line by adding INTERVAL YEAR:

`NUMTODSINTERVAL(VALUE_KEY.VALUE/1000, INTERVAL '123456789' YEAR(9)) AS TIMESTAMP),`

I get this issue:

ORA-01760: illegal argument for function
01760. 00000 -  "illegal argument for function"

Comment: This is essentially [the year 2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem). Your code works with intervals of up to (2^31)-1 seconds, which as an epoch takes you to 2038-01-19 03:14:07 (ignoring leap seconds). The interval data type allows it, the functions don't work though. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fpJfIQjk)

Comment: You could try breaking the time down into minutes and seconds: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/s3lKpu6Q)

Comment: @PonderStibbons There are a few issues with that as: you do not want to `ROUND`, you want `FLOOR` and `MOD`; you want to use `TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000 UTC'` rather than `SYSDATE`; and, it just delays the problem as `9999-12-31 22:59:59.999` still fails as the minutes are too large [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iz4FN1TX).

Comment: "values are like 2999 year" - if those are magic values then you could potentially exclude those or handle them explicitly before you hit the calculation. It will still be a real issue at some point though; hopefully Oracle will find a way to address this before then...

Comment: @MT0 - yep, my fiddle was provisional, just to show the concept :)

Answer (score 2):

You can add the value to a `DATE` and then convert to a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` and add the fractional seconds:

```sql
SELECT value,
       TO_CHAR(
         FROM_TZ(
           CAST(
             DATE '1970-01-01' + TRUNC(VALUE_KEY.VALUE / 1000) / 24 / 60 / 60
             AS TIMESTAMP
           ),
           'UTC'
         ) AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Warsaw'
         + INTERVAL '0.001' SECOND * MOD(VALUE_KEY.VALUE, 1000),
         'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS:FF3TZHTZM'
       ) AS "New Date Format"
FROM   value_key
```

or you can split `VALUE` into a days component and a time component and add them separately (fixing @PonderStibbon's suggestion in comments):

```sql
SELECT value,
       TO_CHAR(
         ( TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000 UTC'
         + INTERVAL '1' DAY * TRUNC(VALUE_KEY.VALUE / 86400000)
         + INTERVAL '0.001' SECOND * MOD(VALUE_KEY.VALUE, 86400000)
         ) AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Warsaw',
         'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS:FF3TZHTZM'
       ) AS "New Date Format"
FROM   value_key
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE value_key (value) AS
  SELECT (DATE '6000-01-01' - DATE '1970-01-01')*24*60*60*1000 + 123 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT (DATE '2999-12-31' + INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND - DATE '1970-01-01')*24*60*60*1000 + 999 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT (DATE '9999-12-31' + INTERVAL '22:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND - DATE '1970-01-01')*24*60*60*1000 + 999 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT (DATE '1969-01-01' - DATE '1970-01-01')*24*60*60*1000 + 222 FROM DUAL;
```

Both outputs:

| VALUE | New Date Format |
| --- | --- |
| 127174492800123 | 6000-01-01T01:00:00:123+0100 |
| 32503679999999 | 3000-01-01T00:59:59:999+0100 |
| 253402297199999 | 9999-12-31T23:59:59:999+0100 |
| -31535999778 | 1969-01-01T01:00:00:222+0100 |

*Note: `2999-12-31T23:59:59.999 UTC` = `3000-01-01T00:59:59:999+0100`.*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZtZieK0v)